# What is the easy way to iterate a std::tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

Currently I think I can do the following

```
apply([](auto&... e) { forward_as_tuple((e.do_something(), 0)...); }, t);
```

Here t is the tuple. This way is not easy to read. Any other ways? Thanks.

Comment: (start with replacing forward_as_tuple with a fold expression)

Comment: This is a simpler case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843684/type-sensitive-tuple-visitor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100178/2089675

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, no. Because `tuple`s are heterogeneous, you cannot have something like:

```
for (auto e : my_tuple)
```

because `e` would potentially need to be a different type in each iteration - and that's a very different kind of iteration than what we're used to in the language. [P1306](https://wg21.link/p1306) is proposing a completely new kind of `for` loop to address this problem, spelled `for...`

Now, I said you need a different type in each iteration. That's not *strictly* true. If your `tuple` is homogenous, you could just turn it into a `std::array`. And even if your `tuple` is heterogeneous, still turn it into an array of `std::any` or an array of `std::variant<Ts...>`, consisting of all the unique types that the `tuple` happens to contain. Maybe that solves your problem, maybe it doesn't.

Otherwise, the only way in the language today is to unpack your tuple through a new scope. That could either be `std::apply` (which gives you *all* the elements in one go) or you could write your own version of it which passes in one element at a time, so you get unary lambdas.