# C++: Using std::apply to iterate through a tuple in 2 parts: up to an index applying a lambda and then after an index applying a different lambda

Tags: c++, slice, stdtuple, stdapply

If I want to iterate through a tuple using `std::apply` but not apply one function to the entire thing, how can I separate the tuple, i.e. apply one function to the first `n` values and another to all values after it?

`some_values` would be a tuple which could have any length and types and `length_of_first_part` (likely named a little less verbosely) would known at compile-time.

```cpp
std::tuple<char, long long, double, long double, float> some_values(33, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8);
const size_t length_of_first_part = 2;
std::apply(
    [](auto&&... current_val) {
        ((std::cout << "(Should be first part) " << current_val << "\n"), ...); //Would obviously do a litle more than cout, but this is just a minimal example
    }, some_values
);

std::apply(
    [](auto&&... current_val) {
        ((std::cout << "(Should be second part) " << current_val << "\n"), ...);
    }, some_values
);
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626856/how-to-split-a-tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave this a shot. Looking at the "possible implementation" here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

It passes an `std::index_sequence` to a helper function to call `std::invoke`. I changed it to pass `std::make_sequence<N>` (N being the split index) instead of the tuple size. Then I passed the inverse (tuple size - N) to call `std::invoke` on the second function:

```cpp
template <int N, typename F1, typename F2, typename Tuple, size_t... I1s, size_t... I2s>
decltype(auto) split_apply_impl(F1&& f1, F2&& f2, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I1s...>, std::index_sequence<I2s...>) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<F1>(f1), std::get<I1s>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F2>(f2), std::get<(I2s+N)>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

template <size_t N, typename F1, typename F2, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) split_apply(F1&& f1, F2&& f2, Tuple&& t)
{
    return split_apply_impl<N>(
        std::forward<F1>(f1), 
        std::forward<F2>(f2),
        std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<N>{},
        std::make_index_sequence<(std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>-N)>{});
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
std::tuple<char, long long, double, long double, float> some_values(33, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8);
constexpr size_t length_of_first_part = 2;
split_apply<length_of_first_part>(
    [](auto&&... current_val) { 
        ((std::cout << "(Should be first part) " << current_val << "\n"), ...); 
    },
    [](auto&&... current_val) {
        ((std::cout << "(Should be second part) " << current_val << "\n"), ...);
    },
    some_values);
```

Proof of concept:
https://godbolt.org/z/6dvMre

Comment: Out of interest, if I were to write out the actual types for the lambdas instead of `auto&&...`, what would they be? I don't mean what they would be in the example, but, e.g. if the tuple was `std::tuple<Ts&...>`, what arguments would the 2 lambdas take relative to that? Fantastic answer by the way :)

Comment: It's passing each tuple element as an argument (see where it extracts each Nth argument with `std::get<N>(...)`). The argument type is that element's type, or `std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts&...>>`