# Exclude first n arguments from parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a function `foo` that calls a function `bar` with a subset of types passed into `foo`'s variadic template. For example:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo() {
  // ...
  template <size_t start_idx, typename... T>
  using param_pack = /*Parameter pack with T[start_idx]...T[N]*/
  auto b = bar<param_pack<2, T...>>();
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to extract a "sub-parameter pack". In the above case
if `T = [int float char double]` then `param_pack<2, T...> = [char double]`

**[EDIT]**

My goal is to be able to use something like this to match event handlers. For example

```
struct ev {};

template <typename... T>
struct event : ev {
  std::tuple<T...> data_;

  event(T&&... d) : data_(std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(d)...)) {}
};

template <typename... Functor>
struct handler {
  std::tuple<Functor...> funcs_;

  handler(Functor&&... f) : funcs_(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Functor>(f)...)) {}

  void handle_message(ev* e) {
    auto ptrs = std::make_tuple(
      dynamic_cast<event<param_pack<1, typename function_traits<F>::args>>*>(e)...
    ); 

    match(ptrs);
  }
};
```

Here `function_traits::args` get a parameter pack for the function arguments and match iterates over the the tuple `funcs_` checking if the `dynamic_cast` was successful and executing the first successful function. I already have these implemented.

The handlers are something like

```
[] (handler* self, <ARGS>) -> void {
  // ...
}
```

I am essentially trying to get rid of the `self` argument.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569567/get-part-of-stdtuple

Comment: Oops... My bad... Making an edit now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set aside the fact that it lacks a check on the index `N` for simplicity, here is a possible solution based on a function declaration (no definition required) and an using declaration:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename... T, std::size_t... I>
std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<N+I, std::tuple<T...>>...>
sub(std::index_sequence<I...>);

template<std::size_t N, typename... T>
using subpack = decltype(sub<N, T...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T) - N>{}));
```

The *good part* of this approach is that you have not to introduce a new type designed around a tuple, then specialize it somehow iteratively.

---

It follows a minimal, working example that uses the code above:

```
#include<functional>
#include<tuple>
#include<cstddef>
#include<type_traits>

template<std::size_t N, typename... T, std::size_t... I>
std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<N+I, std::tuple<T...>>...>
sub(std::index_sequence<I...>);

template<std::size_t N, typename... T>
using subpack = decltype(sub<N, T...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T) - N>{}));

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<subpack<2, int, float, char, double>, std::tuple<char, double>>::value, "!");
}
```

See a full example up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AbHc4NCKR86Gc1CH).

---

The extended version that includes a check on the index `N` would look like this:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename... T, std::size_t... I>
std::enable_if_t<(N < sizeof...(T)), std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<N+I, std::tuple<T...>>...>>
sub(std::index_sequence<I...>);
```

That is the type you can see in the first example once wrapped in a `std::enable_if_t`, nothing more. Again, declaration is enough, no definition required.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to use your own class template instead of an `std::tuple`, you can easily modify the code to do that:

```
#include<functional>
#include<tuple>
#include<cstddef>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename...>
struct bar {};

template<template<typename...> class C, std::size_t N, typename... T, std::size_t... I>
std::enable_if_t<(N < sizeof...(T)), C<std::tuple_element_t<N+I, std::tuple<T...>>...>>
sub(std::index_sequence<I...>);

template<template<typename...> class C, std::size_t N, typename... T>
using subpack = decltype(sub<C, N, T...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T) - N>{}));

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<subpack<bar, 2, int, float, char, double>, bar<char, double>>::value, "!");
}
```

---

**EDIT**

According to the code added to the question, the solution above is still valid. You should just define your `event` class as it follows:

```
struct ev {};

template <typename>
struct event;

template <typename... T>
struct event<std::tuple<T...>>: ev {
    // ...
};
```

This way, when you do this:

```
event<param_pack<1, typename function_traits<F>::args>>
```

You still get a tuple out of `param_pack` (that is the `subpack` using declaration in my example), but it matches the template partial specialization of `event` and the parameter pack is at your disposal as `T...`.

This is the best you can do, for you cannot put a parameter pack in an using declaration. Anyway it just works, so probably it can solve your issue.

Comment: The type is a `std::tuple<T...>` is there a way to get the pack directly i.e., `T...`

Comment: @subzero You cannot put a pack in an using declaration. All what you can is passing the type you want to fill along with the other data and get it back instead of a tuple. Could it work for you? How do you want to use that pack?

Comment: @subzero I added another example to show how you can use your own class template. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have added an example use to the question

Comment: @subzero `function_traits::args` is the list of types you want to store aside?

Comment: I dont want to store them... I want to pass them to the stored functor

Comment: @subzero You can't put them in a using declaration. That's how C++ works, I'm sorry. But if you store them in a tuple you can then unpack it by means of `std::tuple_element` as I did in the example code. That's the best you can do.

Comment: @subzero Answer updated. See the last section. I added a way you can follow to solve your issue. This is the best you can do, really.

Answer (score 3):

You may do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts> struct drop;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct drop<0, Ts...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct drop<N, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename drop<N - 1, Ts...>;
};

// Specialization to avoid the ambiguity
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct drop<0, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
};
```

Comment: I've tried to implement the similar idea but stucked with the fact that the compiler cannot choose the specialization for `N = 0`. Could you please take a look: https://wandbox.org/permlink/u3QOECdxokexLgyG

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: Indeed, an extra specialization is required. [Fixed version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K0Bb3MwjwTtJFU8x).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Though it looks a bit awkward now :(

Comment: The type is a `std::tuple<T...>` is there a way to get the pack directly i.e., `T...`

Comment: Not with a `using`. But you can still change `std::tuple<Ts...>` to `bar<Ts...>` easily afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick but not particularly reusable solution.

```
template <typename Pack, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
void invoke_bar_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    bar<std::tuple_element_t<N + Is, Pack>...>();
}

template <std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
void invoke_bar() {
    auto indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - N>();
    invoke_bar_impl<std::tuple<Ts...>, N>(indices);
}
```