# How to divide a tuple in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I have a question about dividing a tuple, as the title said.

In fact, I can do it using `std::index_sequence`, but the code looks ugly.

Is there an elegant way of accomplishing this?

Here are some code to show what I mean.

```
#include<tuple>
using namespace std;

template<typename THead, typename ...TTails>
void foo(tuple<THead, TTails...> tpl)
{
    tuple<THead> tpl_h { get<0>(tpl) };
    tuple<TTails...> tpl_t { /* an elegent way? */ }
    do_sth(tpl_h, tpl_t);
}

int main()
{
    foo(make_tuple(1, 2.0f, 'c'));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A similar question was asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569567/get-part-of-stdtuple but C+17 answer by ecatmur looks way more short.

Comment: @Swift Thank you, I will go and have a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a C++17-capable compiler, you can use [`apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
auto [tpl_h, tpl_t] = apply([](auto h, auto... t) {
    return pair{tuple{h}, tuple{t...}};
}, tpl);
do_sth(tpl_h, tpl_t);
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/KT2FtL).

Since you're using VS2015.2, which supports C++14 and the later draft [n4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf), you're fairly restricted in the library support available. However, you can use `piecewise_construct`:

```
struct unpacker {
    tuple<THead> tpl_h;
    tuple<TTails...> tpl_t;
    unpacker(THead h, TTails... t) : tpl_h{h}, tpl_t{t...} {}
};
auto unpacked = pair<unpacker, int>{piecewise_construct, tpl, tie()}.first;
do_sth(unpacked.tpl_h, unpacked.tpl_t);
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/6fGpY1).

Comment: Thank you. But I am using VS2015.2(support C++ 14). Is there a method that I can use without replacing my compiler?

Comment: @WangChu: `apply` can be implemented in C++14.

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay, I will try.

Comment: @WangChu found a C++14 solution using `piecewise_construct`, but it's a lot less elegant.